# How to render image from database using DD4T

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t

I am publishing everything to the Broker database, including images.  How do I resolve the images from the Broker database using DD4T?

I found a nice example of resolving images from the filesystem [here](https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/wiki/26_ComponentViews), but this is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next release of DD4T (1.26) includes a new DLL called DD4T.Web written by Quirijn Slings which contains a BinaryDistributionModule class and a BinaryFileManager class that are going to handle both Binaries in the database and on the filesystem.

If you need to do this in a DD4T 1.25 project: here's the relevant portion of the BinaryFileManager class which tries to get a binary from the database:

```
 // the normal situation (where a binary is still in Tridion and it is present on the file system already and it is up to date) is now covered
 // Let's handle the exception situations. 
 IBinary binary = null;
 try
 {
     BinaryFactory.TryFindBinary(urlPath, out binary);
 }
 catch (BinaryNotFoundException)
 {
     LoggerService.Debug("Binary with url {0} not found", urlPath);
     // binary does not exist in Tridion, it should be removed from the local file system too
     if (File.Exists(physicalPath))
     {
        DeleteFile(physicalPath);
     }
     return false;

  }
  return WriteBinaryToFile(binary, physicalPath, dimensions);
```

Take a look at the full [BinaryFileManager](https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/DD4T.Web/Binaries/BinaryFileManager.cs) and [BinaryDistributionModule](https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/DD4T.Web/Binaries/BinaryDistributionModule.cs) classes for more detail.

Comment: The BinaryDistributionModule is an HTTPModule and intercepts the request.  Do I need to add it to the web.config or global.asax?

Comment: I think you can do either programmatically:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239802/programmatically-register-httpmodules-at-runtime or via the config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763179.aspx